# Extracting ZIP files gets stuck on "verifying destination"

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, zip, extract

Recently, my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has been unable to extract any sort of ZIP files, it will always get stuck on "Verifying Destination" on the GUI, see here:
[GUI of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX6VF.png)

I tried running `nautilus` through the command line to see what was going on, and it spits out the following line of codes hundreds of times before inevitably crashing: [Terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fidxM.png)

I've created ZIP files of my own of varying sizes as well as downloading various ones from online; regardless of the contents, size, or creation source, extracting the files simply does not work, and nautilus will crash after a few minutes of idling.

Trying to extract a zip through the command line using `unzip` will give the following error: [unzip terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YBg7.png) (note that the files are never extracted)

However, extracting a tar.xz file works fine, and if I simply drag the files out of archine manager and into a folder, the files end up there without a hitch. This is not a huge inconvinience but I'm very curious as to why this happening, and would also appreciate a fix. So far, I've tried restarting my computer, restarting nautilus, removing and reinstalling nautilus, removing and reinstalling ubuntu-desktop, removing and reinstalling unzip.

Comment: You seem to like using `sudo`: perhaps some permissions in your user configuration are not anymore correct. You could temporarily create a new user, see if the issue persists in a fresh account. If not, then you know it is some damage in your user configuration. If yes, then it is a system wide issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this in the future, it seems to have been an issue with the kernel. I swapped to an older kernel and now unzipping works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem today.

Despite not being able to find a solution when right clicking and pressing extract, I managed to find an alternative method by left clicking on the zip file and extracting the files by pressing the Extract button as shown in the [image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUwTM.png) . You will also need to create a new folder where the extracted files will be placed.

Hope this provides an alternative method if you do not want to switch to an older kernel!